# prompt the user as to whether they want the app to search for an Integer or a String

Tags: java

How to prompt the user as to whether they want the app to search for an Integer or a String using Joption and switch case statements... im so lost on how to code this

Comment: When in doubt, start with [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
    Object[] options = {"Integer Value", "String Value"};

    int choise = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "What do you want to search for?", "Box Title",
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

    switch ((String) options[choise]) {
    case "Integer Value":
        System.out.println("They chose an integer!");
        break;
    case "String Value":
        System.out.println("They chose a string!");
        break;
```

**Step 1:** Create an Object[] of all of the possible options. In this case they are "Integer Value" and "String Value".

**Step 2:** Call the JOptionPane class. We parse in the parent (null), the question, the title of the window, the type of option, the image we want on our option, an icon (null), our options and the default option (options[0]). This method returns an integer that is what the user picked.

**Step 3**: Use the choice in a switch case to do whatever you want. You don't need to have the switch case using strings, it could just use integers but I think it's clearer this way.